# How to define a Generic Collection Type of a Generic Type

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class with the following extension method:

```
public static class CollectionsExtensions
{
    public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this List<T> collection, int size)
    {   
        if (size == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var chunks = new List<List<T>>();
        var chunkCount = collection.Count / size;

        if (collection.Count % size > 0)
            chunkCount++;

        for (var i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++)
            chunks.Add(collection.Skip(i * size).Take(size).ToList());

        return chunks;
    }
}
```

I use a code analyzer which helps pointing out code smells and potential flaws, and for this one I have a suggestion to switch the return type of the method to be of generic type. I've tried changing the signature of the method to be something like this:

```
public static List<U<T>> Split<U,T>(this U<T> collection, int size) where U : IEnumerable<T>
```

But unfortunately it's not working, **so**, is there a proper way to define a class with a method that can return a List of U collections of type T ?

Comment: _"But unfortunately it's not working"_ - what's not working? Can you describe what you mean under that?

Comment: Which code analyzer and what does it say, **exactly**?

Comment: shouldn't it be `List<U>`?

Comment: This should work
`public static List<U> Split<U, T>(this U collection, int size) where U : IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @SeM, it was not building, but I've found the solution.

Comment: @Ovy.Istrate one advice, to avoid continuous Q&A in comment sections, try to first ask yourself - Is your answer to question complete? To avoid dialogues, such: _"It's not working. What is your problem? It not builds. Any errors? It says X is wrong. What is X? It's Z's base class. What is Z?"_ and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are saying this:

```
where U : IEnumerable<T>
```

That means that `U` will be a `List<T>` or some type which is inheriting from `IEnumerable<T>`, so that means your method's return type can be `List<U>` in that case, which will be the  same like `List<IEnumerable<T>>` or `List<List<T>>`.

At the time of using the method the compiler will resolve the type parameters `U` to inject `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` will be the type provided.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it like that:

```
public static List<U> Split<U, T>(this U collection, int size) where U : IEnumerable<T>
```